# How to get the difference between two lists?

Tags: list, scala

I have two lists:

```
val list1 = List("word1","word2","word2","word3","word1")
val list2 = List("word1","word4")
```

I want to remove all occurrences of `list2` elements from `list1`, i.e. I want

```
List("word2","word2","word3") <= list1 *minus* list2
```

I did `list1 diff list2`
which gives me `List("word2","word2","word3","word1")` which is removing only the first occurrence of "word1".

I cannot convert it to sets because I need knowledge about duplicates (see "word2" above). What to do?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use

```
val unwanted = list2.toSet
list1.filterNot(unwanted)
```

to remove all items in `list2` (you don't need knowledge of duplicates in `list2`).

Comment: Why 'bad'? Sets are not bad per se.

Comment: I think he just means "unwanted" -- the items which you don't want in the resulting list.

Comment: @Rick-777 - AmigoNico was right.  I changed the name accordingly!

Comment: For those wondering how this works (since `filterNot` takes in a predicate), note that the `Set` class has `apply(elem: A): Boolean`, which checks for existence of an element in a set.

Answer (score 14):

```
val list1 = List("word1","word2","word2","word3","word1")
val list2 = List("word1","word4") 
list1 diff list2
```

This will do it.

Comment: No. The question explains why.

Answer (score 9):

You could try this:

```
val list1 = List("word1","word2","word2","word3","word1")
val list2 = List("word1","word4")

println(list1.filterNot(list2.contains(_)))
```

Comment: The contains operation on list2 is inefficient - it will do a linear scan for every element of list1, so there are n x m iterations in the inner loop.

Set containment testing is better than that of lists for any non-trivial set because it firstly uses hashcode comparisons to eliminate most cases and only tests string equality in the small number of remaining cases, if any. (How good this is depends on the hashing algorithm in use).

Comment: Set is more efficient, but does not preserve order. If there is any set that preserves order I would like to use it for my case

Comment: I would expect that, for little list, it is more efficient to use directly the list than set, even if it is of linear complexity : first, it removes the toSet duplication, and second lookup in a set is a big constant that cost more than a little linear