# How to select elements of collection based on another of different type?

Tags: scala

I know I can do this:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = List(2,4)
b: List[Int] = List(2, 4)

scala> a.filterNot(b.toSet)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 3)
```

But I'd like to select elements of a collection based on their integer key, as in the following:

```
case class N (p: Int , q: Int)
val x = List(N(1,100), N(2,200), N(3,300))
val y = List(2,4)
val z = .... ?
Z // want Z to be ((N1,100), (N3,300)) after removing the items of type N with 'p' 
  // matching any item in list y.
```

I know one way to do it is is something like the following which makes the above broken code work:

```
val z = x.filterNot(e => y.contains(e.p))
```

but this seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you think it is inefficient? Did you do any performance measurements?

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278098/scala-difference-of-two-lists

Comment: Convert `y` to `Set` first would be good enough, I think?

Comment: Do you mean using the first approach (match on set) or second approach (contains()) ? Regardless, I'm missing something.

Comment: @WillIAm `Set.contains` is more efficient than `List.contains`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `contains` is that the search will be a linear search and you are looking at `O(N^2)` solution(which is still OK, if the dataset is not large)

Anyways, a simple solution can be to use Binary search to get `O(NlnN)` solution. You can easily convert val y to Array from list and then use java's binary search method.

```
scala> case class N(p: Int, q: Int)
defined class N

scala>   val x = List(N(1, 100), N(2, 200), N(3, 300))
x: List[N] = List(N(1,100), N(2,200), N(3,300))

scala>  val y = Array(2, 4) // Using Array directly.
y: Array[Int] = Array(2, 4)

scala> val z = x.filterNot(e => java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(y, e.p) >= 0)
z: List[N] = List(N(1,100), N(3,300))
```

Comment: The set look up(http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) is a constant time operation. @Dima solution will be much better.

Answer (score 4):

Just do

```
val z = y.toSet
x.filterNot {z.contains(_.p)}
```

That's linear.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is only linear _if_ the hash function distributes `y`'s elements well.

Comment: Yeah, well ... As linear as it gets :)